# Axios Promise.allSettled() Issue

Tags: javascript, http, promise, axios

I am using axios to make some API request like so

```
var urls = ['url1','url2','url3']
var promises = urls.map(url=> axios.get(url));
const responses = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
console.log(responses)
```

I know that these url returning 400 with a fault message. But the console show

```
]
{ status: 'fulfilled', value: undefined }
{ status: 'fulfilled', value: undefined }
{ status: 'fulfilled', value: undefined }
[
```

Shouldn't I get something in value, like the status code and the fault message?

Comment: you should receive some response. Show your full code and share axios version please. https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-grass-duk0i?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Please support the urls you're trying to access , I am almost sure the problem would be much clearer if we can see their response